# AVAudioPlayer audio not playing when its set and played from different methods

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift2, avaudioplayer

I have an app with different button press sounds. I'm trying to use two functions to set the next button press sound and then play it. The idea is to load the audio file for when the next button is pressed, and then finally play it through a different function when a button is pressed. Using `prepareToPlay()`, this should make playback faster.

The problem is that when I press a button, I hear 'silence'. I say 'silence' because my speakers actually receive some signal, but its too week to be heard.

Here's my code:

```
func loadNextButtonPressSound() {

    let randomSoundIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(pressSounds.count)))
    pressSoundPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pressSounds[randomSoundIndex])
    pressSoundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    pressSoundPlayer.delegate = self

}


func playButtonPressSound() { // called when a button is pressed

    if(StoredSettings.instance.getEnableSoundsSetting()) {
        pressSoundPlayer.play()
        loadNextButtonPressSound()
    }
}
```

If I instead merge the codes to form this:

internal func playButterPressSound() {

```
if(StoredSettings.instance.getEnableSoundsSetting()) {
    let randomSoundIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(pressSounds.count)))
    pressSoundPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pressSounds[randomSoundIndex])
    pressSoundPlayer.play()

}
```

}

It starts working (i.e. I hear button presses), but it defeats the purpose of using `prepareToPlay()` to preload the next sound.

Any suggestions on how to make the first code above work ?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, did you get anywhere with this? I seem to be having a similar issue.